# Casting base to derived class according to a type flag

Tags: c++, oop

I have been writing an event class for my game engine and i came across to the following problem:

Is casting a base class object to a derived class object given a type flag a good programming design?

Let me give you the following simple example. 
I have this enum holding the categories of the events:

```
enum DisplayEventType
{
    DET_UNSET,
    DET_WINDOW_EVENT,
    DET_KEYBOARD_EVENT,
    DET_MOUSE_EVENT,
    DET_JOYSTICK_EVENT
};
```

This is the base class of all the events:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<DisplayEventData> DisplayEventDataMP;

class DisplayEvent
{
    private:

        // The type of the display event
        DisplayEventType mType;

        // The data of the event
        DisplayEventDataMP mEventData;

    public:

        // Constructor
        DisplayEvent(DisplayEventType type = DisplayEventType::DET_UNSET, DisplayEventDataMP eventData = std::unique_ptr<DisplayEventData>((DisplayEventData*) 0));

        // Retrieves the event type of the current event
        DisplayEventType GetType() const;

        // Sets the event type of the current event
        void SetType(DisplayEventType type);

        // Retrieves a raw pointer to the event data of the current event
        DisplayEventData* GetEventData() const;

        // Sets the event data of the current event
        void SetEventData(DisplayEventDataMP eventData);
};
```

This is the base class of the event data:

```
class DisplayEventData
{
    public:

        // Virtual destructor, for the deallocation of the interface implementors to work
        virtual ~DisplayEventData();
};
```

And these are the derived classes

```
class WindowEventData : public DisplayEventData
{
    // Window event data specific data and methods
};

class KeyboardEventData : public DisplayEventData
{
    // Keyboard event data specific data and methods
};

class MouseEventData : public DisplayEventData
{
    // Mouse event data specific data and methods
};

class JoystickEventData : public DisplayEventData
{
    // Joystick event specific data and methods
};
```

Some basic usage would be this:

```
// Poll for next event in the queue
DisplayEvent ev;
display->PollEvent(ev); // Fills ev with the needed data

if (ev.GetType() == DisplayEventType::DET_KEYBOARD_EVENT)
{
    KeyboardEventData* kev = static_cast<KeyboardEventData>(ev.GetEventData());
    // Do stuff
}
```

Is the above design viable/correct? If not what would a better alternative be in terms of object oriented or even generic programming?

Comment: Why have a separate enum and not just do a sequence of dynamic casts?

Comment: Because dynamic casts not only add overhead, they are a really bad design in my opinion too.

Comment: You think your enums don't add any overhead and aren't really bad design?

Comment: dynamic_cast is being performed at the runtime while static_cast not. As for the design part, this is what i am trying to find! :P

Comment: Your conditional checks are performed at runtime. There's no magic free lunch :-S Your enums just duplicate the type discrimination information that is *already* being tracked in the RTTI structure.

Comment: Maybe this question belongs on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: "Correct" design in a situation like this is to not have any enum type, and instead declare a pure virtual method `Handle()` in the base class, which each derived class implements differently.  Then, instead of `if (ev.GetType() == DisplayEventType::DET_KEYBOARD_EVENT) { ... }`, you simply call `ev.Handle();`.  Why is this considered "correct"?  Because it's open for extension (new event subclasses can be added later without any need to change superclass code).

Comment: @j_random_hacker An event doesn't handle itself though does it? Different listeners will need to specify different handling code.

Comment: @GaryBuyn: I only skimmed the code, but it doesn't seem to mention listeners -- it seems to be just some code for centralised handling of all events.  If the OP wants objects to be able to register their desire to listen for particular events, the Visitor pattern is the "correct" way to do this (it enables the set of events to remain open for extension).

Comment: Generally speaking, that is not the best design. Any time you have to perform a cast, you are dealing with the symptoms of a less than perfect design.

Comment: Yes this is what i also believe. So what could be a perfect design?

Comment: @dyp Should i transfer it somehow or create a new Question in CodeReview?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a single 'correct' design for an event system, especially within a game engine. I recently implemented an event system for my own game engine, which I will share the implementation details below. It may or may not be the best fit for your problem, but it should produce some ideas in your head for alternative designs.

Note: My event system is not completely optimized yet. Some simple optimizations would include hashing strings and or using an unordered map instead of a map.

Key Design Points:

- The core design idiom in my event system is to have a non-template base class and a template child class which inherits from the non-template base class
- All event functions must conform to a specific function signature defined in the TypedEventSubscriber class
- Any number of parameters and arguments can be passed by utilizing the NamedProperties, NamedProperty, and TypedNamedProperties classes, for which the NamedProperty and TypedNamedProperties classes follows the bullet point mentioned in the first bullet
- Member function pointers are used for callback, so specific objects can receive events
- No inheritance is necessary for the event system; anyone can register and fire events through talking to the EventManager singleton
- Dynamic Casting is used for parameter retrieval from callback functions within NamedProperties class. While Dynamic Cast is not always best practice, using it allows us to have 0..N possible parameters passed through the callback functions.

Example of non-template NamedProperty class ( Very simple )

```
class NamedProperty {
public:
    explicit NamedProperty();
    virtual ~NamedProperty();

};
```

Example of templated TypeNamedProperty class

```
template < typename T_PropertyDataType >
class TypedNamedProperty : public NamedProperty {
public:
    friend class NamedProperties;

    explicit TypedNamedProperty<T_PropertyDataType>() {}
    virtual ~TypedNamedProperty() {}

    // Inline Mutators
    inline void TypedNamedProperty<T_PropertyDataType>::setData( const T_PropertyDataType & data ) {
        m_data = data;
    }


    inline void TypedNamedProperty<T_PropertyDataType>::getData( T_PropertyDataType & data ) {
        data = m_data;
    }

private:
    T_PropertyDataType      m_data;

};
```

Example of NamedProperties class which is the container for the NamedProperty params. It returns an enum indicating the status of the property retrieval. Because I am handling 0..N possible params of any type, getProperty is a template function which will use dynamic cast for the type provided. If the dynamic cast fails (Failed dynamic casts return nullptr), it will set the appropriate enum value and return. If it succeeds, it will return the correct parameter.

```
typedef enum {

    PROPERTY_GET_SUCCESS,
    PROPERTY_GET_FAILED_NO_SUCH_PROPERTY,
    PROPERTY_GET_FAILED_WRONG_TYPE,
    PROPERTY_GET_FAILED_NULLPTR,
} PropertyResult;

class NamedProperties {
public:

    ~NamedProperties();

    // Mutators
    template <typename T_PropertyDataType>
    inline PropertyResult getProperty( const std::string & propertyName, T_PropertyDataType & valueOut ) {

        PropertyResult result;
        std::map<std::string, NamedProperty *>::iterator itProp;
        itProp = m_namedProperties.find( propertyName );
        if ( itProp != m_namedProperties.end() ) {
            // property found in the map... Need to cast it to check if the type is correct
            NamedProperty * retrievedResult = itProp->second;
            if ( retrievedResult == nullptr ) {
                result = PROPERTY_GET_FAILED_NULLPTR;
                return result;
            } 

            TypedNamedProperty<T_PropertyDataType> * propertyWithType = dynamic_cast<TypedNamedProperty<T_PropertyDataType> *>( retrievedResult );
            if ( propertyWithType != nullptr ) {
                propertyWithType->getData( valueOut );
                result = PROPERTY_GET_SUCCESS;
            } else {
                result = PROPERTY_GET_FAILED_WRONG_TYPE;
            }
        } else {
            // No such property exists in the map
            result = PROPERTY_GET_FAILED_NO_SUCH_PROPERTY;

        }
        return result;
    } // end getProperty


    template <typename T_PropertyDataType>
    inline void setProperty( const std::string & propertyName, const T_PropertyDataType & propertyValue ) {

        TypedNamedProperty<T_PropertyDataType> * typedProperty = new TypedNamedProperty<T_PropertyDataType>;
        typedProperty->setData( propertyValue );
        m_namedProperties.insert( std::pair< std::string, TypedNamedProperty<T_PropertyDataType>*>( propertyName, typedProperty ) );
    }

protected:
    std::map<std::string, NamedProperty* >          m_namedProperties;
};
```

Example of non-template EventSubscriberBase class, which is the base class stored in the EventSystemSubscribers data structure in the EventSystemManager singleton. Notice the virtual callCallbackFunction which is pure virtual.

```
class EventSubscriberBase {
public:
    virtual ~EventSubscriberBase() {}
    EventSubscriberBase() {}

    virtual void callCallbackFunction( NamedProperties & params ) = 0;

    virtual void * getSubscriberObjectPointer() = 0;
};
```

Example of the templated TypedEventSubscriber class

```
#include "EventSubscriberBase.hpp"

template< typename T_SubscriberType >
class TypedEventSubscriber : public EventSubscriberBase {

typedef void ( T_SubscriberType::*ObjectMemberFunctionType )( NamedProperties & );

public:
    virtual ~TypedEventSubscriber<T_SubscriberType>() {}
    explicit TypedEventSubscriber<T_SubscriberType>() {
        m_subscriberObject = nullptr;
    }

    virtual void callCallbackFunction( NamedProperties & params ) {
        (m_subscriberObject->*m_callbackFunction)(params);
    }


    void setCallbackFunction( ObjectMemberFunctionType callbackFunction ) {
        m_callbackFunction = callbackFunction;
    }


    void setSubscriber( T_SubscriberType * subscriber ) {
        assert( subscriber != nullptr );
        m_subscriberObject = subscriber;
    }


    T_SubscriberType * getSubscriber() {
        return m_subscriberObject;
    }

    virtual void * getSubscriberObjectPointer() {
        return m_subscriberObject;
    }

private:

    T_SubscriberType *          m_subscriberObject;
    ObjectMemberFunctionType    m_callbackFunction;
};
```

Notice there is a typedef for a Member Function Pointer. This is the reason a template class is being used. This allows any class to register a callback function of its type by providing a template parameter. Here is an example of how game code may register an event...

In a .hpp header

```
void saveFileCallbackFunc( NamedProperties& namedProps );
```

In the .cpp file

```
// Call this function in the CTOR or appropriate initialize function
RegisterEventCallbackForObject( "EventNameForCallbackHere", this, &FireAntGame::saveFileCallbackFunc );

// The callback function definition
void FireAntGame::saveFileCallbackFunc( NamedProperties& namedProps ) {

    unsigned int fileBufferSize = 0;
    char* fileBuffer = nullptr;

    namedProps.getProperty( SF_FILE_BUFFER_STRING, fileBuffer );
    namedProps.getProperty( SF_FILE_BUFFER_SIZE_STRING, fileBufferSize );
}
```

Example of the EventSystem singleton class function implementations for registering and firing events. The important detail to notice is that the singleton stores a map of EntitySubscriberBase class pointers instead of the child template class TypedEntitySubscriber.

```
template< typename T_RegisteringObjectType, typename T_ObjectMethodType >
    void registerEvent( const std::string & eventName, T_RegisteringObjectType * classObject, T_ObjectMethodType callbackFunction ) {
        assert( classObject != nullptr );
        TypedEventSubscriber< T_RegisteringObjectType > * eventSubscriber = new TypedEventSubscriber< T_RegisteringObjectType >;
        eventSubscriber->setSubscriber( classObject );
        eventSubscriber->setCallbackFunction( callbackFunction );

        std::map< std::string, std::vector<EventSubscriberBase*>>::iterator it;
        it = m_eventSubscribers.find( eventName );
        if ( it != m_eventSubscribers.end() ) {

            std::vector<EventSubscriberBase*>& eventSubVec = it->second;
            eventSubVec.push_back( eventSubscriber );
        } else {

            // Event did not previously exist
            std::vector<EventSubscriberBase*> eventSubVec;
            eventSubVec.push_back( eventSubscriber );
            std::pair<std::string,std::vector<EventSubscriberBase*>> elementToInsert;
            elementToInsert.first = eventName;
            elementToInsert.second = eventSubVec;
            m_eventSubscribers.insert(elementToInsert);
        }
    }



void fireEvent( const std::string & eventName, NamedProperties & params ) {

        std::map<std::string,std::vector<EventSubscriberBase*>>::iterator itFind;
        itFind = m_eventSubscribers.find( eventName );
        if ( itFind != m_eventSubscribers.end() ) {

            // Someone has registered for this event
            std::vector<EventSubscriberBase*> & subscribersVector = itFind->second;

            for ( size_t i = 0; i < subscribersVector.size(); ++i ) {
                EventSubscriberBase * eventSubscriber = subscribersVector[i];
                eventSubscriber->callCallbackFunction( params );
            }
        }
    }
```

The beauty of this design is that any object can register for an event without inheritance.
This also means an enum does not have to be created for every possible class type involved. It also allows for 0..N parameters passed in the callback functions through the NamedProperties class.  If a property does not exist when requesting it from the NamedProperties class, a default value is returned (which can be specified by user if you wish).

Ultimately, the key take away is the use of the non-template base class with a templated child class. Without this design idiom, it would all fall apart. This allows our data structures to leverage polymorphism with a base class pointer which can invoke callback functions on any member function type or pass in parameters through NamedProperties of any type! In my opinion, this allows for the most flexibility for an event system.

Sorry for the long post! Hopefully this provides an idea for an implementation of an event system.